# SharePoint 2007 Analytics Package

Tags: sharepoint, analytics

While the built-in analytics of MOSS2007 are nice to have - they are inadequate at the same time. Any ideas where I can look for a more comprehensive package? Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Nintex Reporting](http://www.nintex.com/en-US/Products/Pages/NintexReporting2008.aspx).  We just bought it and it seems like a nice enhancement on top of the out of the box usage reporting.  They seem to do everything "right" from a supportability point of view too, so you don't have a tool in there monkeying directly with your content databases.

I've also heard claims from our Webtrends rep that they have some SharePoint-specific capabilities, if that's a product suite you already happen to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for Usage reporting, you could surf over to http://www.intlock.com/ and look into CardioLog too.